# Strange spacing for left navigation bar button

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I don't understand why I'm getting this `_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView` on the `rootViewController` of my `NavigationViewController`?

I want the leading spacing of menu icon to be the same as for search icon (right one).

Why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: what is constant value for leading constraint for that button?

Comment: seems like your image is bigger, that's why. You should try to open this .png or jpg file in preview (application on mac), and try to adjust size as will as crop some part out that is not required. Then re-save this in assets and i think it should work

Comment: How are you adding the image to the left bar item? Via code? Can you paste the code? Or via storyboard?

Comment: I added it via storyboard. I'll check my images size

Comment: Thanks, the problem was actually with wrong icon size.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one extra UIBarButtonItem in LeftBarButtonItems of your navigation Controller to remove extra space.

This Code may help you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *displayBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_DISPLAY_IMAGE_NAME"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(leftBarButtonItemAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *removeSpacerBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    removeSpacerBarButton.width = -15; // adjust width value according to your requirement
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[removeSpacerBarButton, displayBarButton] animated:NO];

}
-(void)leftBarButtonItemAction:(id)sender{

    //left bar button action
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with icon size. I exported icon in PDF and used it.